# Making an outside machine visible to private network

Tags: networking, dhcp, nfs, mount

I'm trying to make a server visible to all computers on a separate network without doing anything to the server, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this.  I really just need to access one folder but my attempts at NFS mounting failed since I can't NFS mount a mounted folder.  Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: So the server and computers are in two separate PRIVATE networks? Something like: server's ip is 10.0.0.5 and computer's ip are 10.0.1.xx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN to link the two networks together? Without knowing what firewalls you're using on each of the two private networks it would be hard to give options, but basically you'd need something to establish a link between the two systems or networks to make them visible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the router(s)? You could do that by adding a **static route** to the server you want to make visible and possible some **ACL** rules.